# React - How can I get a re-render to happen in my table?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a table which starts off with data from a store which can then be edited by row. When the editing has been completed, a button is clicked which saves the new values and should present them in the table. However, this is not happening for me. I have been stuck on this for a while now and have tried various things but none of them have worked. I think it may be a problem with the state but I can't figure out how to change it to make it work!

The code I have currently is:

Table:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableWithDataHeader from './TableWithDataHeader.jsx';
import TableWithDataBody from './TableWithDataBody.jsx';
import TableWithDataRowForm from './TableWithDataRowForm.jsx';
import {updateRowHistory} from '../../actions/DALIActions';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableWithData extends React.Component {
    state = {rows: [], isEditing: false, input: null};

    componentDidMount() {
        let rows = this.state.rows;
        rows.push({id: AppStore.getRowId(), cells: AppStore.getCells().historycells});
        this.setState({rows});
        console.log(rows);
    }

    handleEdit = (row) => {
        this.setState({isEditing: true});
    };

    handleInputChange = (newCellValuesArray) => {
        let input = this.state.input;
        input = newCellValuesArray;
        this.setState({input});
    };

    editStop = (row) => {
        this.setState({isEditing: false});
    };

    handleSubmit = (access_token, row_id) => {
        let newCellValuesArray = this.state.input;
        updateRowHistory(access_token, row_id, newCellValuesArray);
        this.setState({isEditing: false});
    };

    render() {

        let {rows, isEditing, input} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <TableWithDataHeader />
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {rows.map(row => this.state.isEditing ? 
                                <TableWithDataRowForm 
                                    key={row.id} 
                                    cells={row.cells} 
                                    editStop={this.editStop.bind(null, row.id)} 
                                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                                    handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                                /> 
                                : 
                                <TableWithDataBody 
                                    key={row.id} 
                                    cells={row.cells} 
                                    handleEdit={this.handleEdit.bind(null, row.id)} 
                                />
                            )}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Data table starts with:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TableWithDataBody extends React.Component {
    state = {cells: this.props.cells};

    handleEdit = () => {
        this.props.handleEdit();
    };

    render() {

        let {cells} = this.state;

        return (
            <tr>
                {cells.map(cell => {
                    return <td key={cell.id} className="text-center">{cell.contents}</td>
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleEdit}><i className="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

In-row edit form:

```
import React from 'react';
import AppStore from '../../stores/AppStore';

export default class TableWithDataRowForm extends React.Component {
    state = {cells: this.props.cells, newCellValues: []};

    onChange = (e) => {
        let newCellValues = this.state.newCellValues;
        newCellValues[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({newCellValues});
        console.log(newCellValues);
        let newCellValuesArray = [];
        for (let key in newCellValues) {
            if (newCellValues.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                newCellValuesArray.push({contents: newCellValues[key]});
            }
        }
        console.log(newCellValuesArray);
        this.props.handleInputChange(newCellValuesArray);
    };

    editStop = () => {
        this.props.editStop();
    };

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        let access_token = AppStore.getToken();
        let row_id = AppStore.getRowId();

        this.props.handleSubmit(access_token, row_id);
    };

    render() {

        let {cells, newCellValues} = this.state;

        return (
            <tr>
                {cells.map(cell => {
                    return <td key={cell.id} className="text-center"><input type="text" className="form-control" id={cell.id} defaultValue={cell.contents} onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
                })}
                <td>
                    <button className="btn btn-default"><i className="fa fa-ban" onClick={this.editStop}></i>Cancel</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success"><i className="fa fa-cloud" onClick={this.handleSubmit}></i>Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Help with examples would be much appreciated, sorry if the code is a bit of a mess right now!

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I don't see where you're editing the `rows` state? The change handler just changes the `input`, and you aren't passing the input down to the data table.

The only time I see `rows` being set is in `componentDidMount`, which explains why it's being populated, but not changed.

Comment: Yeah I know but how can I update the rows with the new values of the cells? Would it be best to use something like componentWillUpdate or some sort of custom function?

Comment: Just call `setState({ rows })` every time your rows change on the top component. Also, you should _only_ have state on your top TableWithData component. All children should just have read-only props, and invoke callbacks to mutate the parent component's state.

Comment: Yes I know what needs to happen but I'm stuck on the how! I think I've confused myself by staring at the code for too long, and the fix is probably a lot easier than I'm telling myself it is at this point!